# Find Root Iteration

Tags: polynomials, equation-solving

I have an iterative sum from $k=0$ to $k=n$ where the resulting sum is a polynomial of degree $n$.

I want to find the numerical root of this polynomial using FindRoot, starting from $x_0$ where the root I'm interested in is converging to some value. However I only know this $x_0$ for small $n \sim 60$.

Then FindRoot will give me a more precise $x_0$ and I can use this to find the root for $n=65$. I then use this root as my $x_0$ for $n=70$ etc. etc.

However I can only really increase $n$ by $5$ each time as I don't know where the root is converging and if I increase $n$ by more, FindRoot starts finding other roots which I know aren't the value I'm looking for.

How I can set it up so that I can run to $n=300$, for example, where FindRoot will use the root found $5$ iterations ago as its $x_0$?

Here's a sample:

```
max=90;
f[[0]]=1;

For[n=1,n<=max,n=n+1,
f[[n]]=Sum[f[[k]]Coefficient[S,y^k],{k,0,n}]];

MySum=Sum[f[[i]],{i,0,max}]

FindRoot[MySum ,{x,x_0},WorkingPrecision->7]
```

where $S$ is some polynomial $S(x,y)$

Comment: Please add working code to make this question easier to understand and answer and more useful for other visitors.

Comment: @YvesKlett I would have. But my code are far too specific, tailored and long for it to be helpful for others. It's using about 20 predefined functions and impossible to understand without the whole notebook. Apologies

Comment: Probably you can try then to define a minimum working example that includes the features you need.

Comment: You should *definitely* go a for a MWE then. Without any code, this will likely be closed. Also, having to make up sample code to fit your verbal explanations is not very attractive.

Comment: @YvesKlett Can you show me where to find out how to copy mathematic code to this site appropriately?

Comment: Just paste the *Mathematica* code here and format it as "Code Sample" (the editor has a button for that). Subscripts and fancy typesetting are best avoided for readability. If you have major problems, paste it anyway and someone will probably help you out with the formatting.

Comment: @YvesKlett Is my edit sufficient?

Comment: As of now, your code does not run when pasted (missing /mismatched brackets?). You can also use additional code to make retracing your steps easier.

Comment: @YvesKlett It think that should do it. Hopefully it's OK to understand what I mean. I basically need $x_0$ to be automatically refreshed as $n$ runs from $0$ to $max$

Comment: What is `x_0`? I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Can you also supply a sample `S`? Your code really should produce some viable output.

Comment: @YvesKlett But the problem is this is very far from my actual code and I have convergence for a very specific reason. I will never be able to give a sample with guaranteed convergence and so I have no idea what $x_0$ is either.

Comment: But without some working code it will be very difficult to reproduce your problem properly.

Comment: @YvesKlett I understand. But I'm not looking for a complete fix, just an idea on how to achieve what I'm asking

Comment: mysum is not even a function of x in your sample

Comment: @george2079 It is now

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes thanks for noticing. However, it of course doesn't affect the roots that I'm trying to find. So you can define $f[[0]]$ as any constant

Comment: @MichaelE2 No this is the very definition of $f_n$. As explained in the comments above, the sample code I gave is wrong because I'm finding it impossible to generate a sample code as convergence is quite unique in my case; but my case is 5 workbooks long. Hence I'm just really looking for some ideas from somebody

Comment: @MichaelE2 You're right, this is very much Mathematics, but I need Mathematica for my calculations. As I said, there will be problems with any sample code I give; but my actual code is perfectly set up; just too detailed to put here. This question is just to find a more efficient way of finding roots of a polynomial I have.

Comment: OK.  I've posted code that "works", but left the `f[[0]]` issue in.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example using a prior solution as the starting value for the next step:

```
polyn[x_?NumericQ, n_] := Normal@Series[ Sin[y], {y, 0, n}] /. y -> x
sol[7] = x /. FindRoot[ polyn[x, 7], {x, 3}]
Do[ sol[n] = x /. FindRoot[ polyn[x, n], {x, sol[n - 1]}], {n, 8, 20} ]

DiscretePlot[sol[n] - Pi, {n, 7, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This runs without errors.  One definitely should not use the [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Head.html) of an expression (e.g. `f[[0]]`) as a numeric variable in an array as the OP does, but I didn't want to rewrite everything.  One normally uses `f[[k+1]]` to correspond to degree `k` and program the off-by-one indices throughout.  Then the other *Mathematica* functions that work so efficiently on [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/List.html) can be used in your project.

```
max = 90;
f = ConstantArray[0, max];
S = x^2 + 3 x y + x y^3;
f[[0]] = 1;

For[n = 1, n <= max, n = n + 1, 
  f[[n]] = Sum[f[[k]] Coefficient[S, y, k], {k, 0, n}]];

MySum = Sum[f[[i]], {i, 0, max}]

FindRoot[MySum, {x, -1}, WorkingPrecision -> 7]

(*
  1 + 90 x^2 + 267 x^3 + 87 x (x^2 + 3 x^3)
  {x -> -1.011827}
*)
```

Finding a good starting point for `FindRoot` might be a problem.  Since `MySum` is a polynomial, one can also use `NSolve`:

```
NSolve[MySum, x]
(*
  {{x -> -1.01183}, {x -> -0.380488},
   {x -> 0.0179959 - 0.0981234 I}, {x -> 0.0179959 + 0.0981234 I}}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for working with my slightly void question. So yes I use NSolve to find a good starting point (I should note: I don't use Nsolve for very large max because it breaks down as my polynomial is too large. Hence FindRoot seems to be my only option.) However I can't see how this code updates $x_0$ as $n$ runs from $0$ to $max$. If I use the "starting point" the whole way, the root quickly gets too far from this value and FindRoot starts finding other roots which I'm not interested in.

Comment: @user13223423 You provided no code for $x_0$.  I have no idea what you want to do with it.  The way you use it, it is just a starting point for `FindRoot`.  You'll have to figure out how to get a close enough starting point to the root you seek.  By the way, you should write it in *Mathematica* as `x0`.  The expression `x_0` is a `Pattern`, not a number.

Comment: For each max, my polynomial has a different root. As I increase max (manually), the root starts moving until soon the root it is too far away from my starting point for FindRoot to locate it. My question is: how can I can set this up so that the starting point for FindRoot changes each time $n$ increases from $0$ to max, and uses the root found from the same calculation but max-1. This way, my "starting point" will always be close enough to the root I want for FindRoot to find it. But sorry, this seems to have wasted your time

Comment: @user13223423 If you can say what to change `x0` to each time, I can write code to do that.  I don't have time to solve the problem of how to determine the starting point, and one might need to know all the details of the problem to do that.  You seem to know something about how it moves.  Can you not use that to get somewhat close?  Or can you always find two numbers, `x1`, `x2` that bracket the root (for which the polynomial is pos. and neg.).  If so, look at the `FindRoot` help.  E.g. `FindRoot[f, {x, x0, x1, x2}]`.

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks for the help